# How to load WordPress on non WP page?

Tags: options, wp-load.php

I want to use the `get_option()` function of wordpress in one of my theme's files, which is not related to WP, it is just located in the same directory of the other theme files. I need this file because of some extra IPN paypal related actions, but I need some values from the options table that exists in WP to be called in this page in order for it to work. I know I can't just use `get_option()` as this file is overlooked by wordpress. Is there any approach by including some parts of wordpress in my theme to make this functionality only work?

Comment: I retagged your question. Hint: Just take a look inside [tag:wp-load.php].

Comment: Have you thought about getting these values out of the database using a custom mysql query? Loading the entire WordPress system for a couple of option values might be overkill. For maintainability I recommend Abdussamads [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/69186) (build it into a plugin)

Answer (score 11):

The shortest way is to load `wp-load.php` and abort the loading of the template engine (Note: You couldn't do that, if you'd be loading the header file, like you see it on many sites in the interweb).

```
# No need for the template engine
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
# Load WordPress Core
// Assuming we're in a subdir: "~/wp-content/plugins/current_dir"
require_once( '../../../wp-load.php' );
```

Comment: Is there more docs on `WP_USE_THEMES` than https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop ? :)

Comment: @jave.web Sure: [The source code cross file search](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=WP_USE_THEMES).

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way is include `wp-load.php` file. This file will loads all WP core, so you can use WP functions such as `get_option` in your PHP file:

```
include 'path/to/wp-load.php';

echo get_option( 'option_name' );
```

Comment: +1 But by above answer, you can delete "the simplest" ;)

Comment: One line (including `wp-load.php`) vs. multiple lines (plugin comments in the beginning), that's the simplest, lol.

Answer (score 4):

Turn your external file into a WordPress plugin. That way you'll have full access to WP core functions.

Comment: This would make your life much easier in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

This *should* work on any WordPress installation:

```
<?php
function load_wp_load() {
  $wp_did_header = true;
  require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/index.php');
  $matches = preg_grep('/wp-blog-header.php/', get_included_files());
  if (!empty($matches)) {
    $abspath = dirname(reset($matches)) . '/';
    define('ABSPATH', $abspath);
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php');
  }
}
?>
```